# Changing Input Source not working in some apps

Tags: input-source

I have a couple of Input Sources set up (Australian and Teknia Greek, the latter added into `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts`). These work correctly in some apps (e.g. Chrome, TextMate), but in other apps (all Office apps, TextEdit, Notes) I am unable to use Teknia Greek. Even if this is selected while focused on another app, as soon as I focus back on one of these apps, the Input Source switches back to Australian. This only affects my MacBook Pro. My iMac has the same setup and works correctly. Both are running Mojave.

Comment: Sounds like something messed up in your account in the Macbook Pro.  Try a safe boot and creating a new user account.

Comment: Unfortunately the same thing occurs on a new account.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I have been struggling for days to get TekniaGreek to work on my MacBook Pro (as it does on my iMac), but see exactly what you experience.